# Performance of the Android Virtual Device

Tags: android, performance

The Android virtual device (a simulated Android environment) doesn't run very smoothly on my machine. Scrolling is quite sluggish.

Is that normal?

EDIT: Just noticed that a AVD running Android 1.6 has a significantly better performance compared to the AVDs running on 2.1 and 2.2.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Android, but on iOS there are some things where the emulator is 100x slower than actual hardware, and other times when the hardware is 100x slower than the emulator. You cannot use the emulator to test performance. You have to do that on the actual target hardware. You need access to a few devices with different levels of performance (beware of non-obvious traps, for example an old GFX card on a small phone can be faster than a state of the art GFX card on a larger tablet)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its normal unless you have like 4GB of RAM, an SSD, and a good processor. Out of all those, RAM is probably the most important though since your basically running a VM(Virtual Machine) on a VM.

Comment: I can expect my apps to have a better performance on an actual phone, right?

Comment: Yeah, it'll run a good deal better.  Especially on the current gen devices (Nexus One, HTC Evo, etc.)

Comment: Oh yes, much much faster. For example, I put a list of 2239 categories in a Dictionary -- it took 40 seconds to load on my emulator and only 3 seconds to do it on my Moto Droid.

Comment: Try to use the emulator as a measurement on how your app would run on the crappiest device available on the market. If your app runs acceptable on the emulator it will run great on the most devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dedicated GPU on your machine, you can enable GPU acceleration on the AVD to make the graphics-related processing, such as animations etc, much faster. It is NOT enabled by default, and the developers page even said that it might not be compatible with every GPU out there, but it is worth a try. You can enable it by editing your AVD, and in the hardware section click "New", add "GPU emulation", and set it to "yes".

This is also assuming you have enough RAM. 4GB is sufficient to run eclipse + the Jellybean AVD (with WXGA720 resolution) on Ubuntu 12.04 Unity. I still have 800 MB of free RAM (I do not have swap space).